# Python djnago coverage : The name "coverage" is not recognized as the name of the cmdlet

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pycharm, code-coverage

I'm using python 3.10, django 4, windows 10, when I type into the console, coverage report outputs an error

coverage : The name "coverage" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, as well as the presence and correctness of the path, and then try again.
line:1 sign:1

- coverage
- 
- CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (coverage:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

coverage I have installed

I tried to install coverage via pip and through the pychrm interface I tried to enter python coverage but nothing helped

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.